# How can I create an instance of an Object in React..?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, frontend

I am very new to react and javascript, but I am trying to build a simple ToDo App. It wasn't complicated until I wanted to read data from a file and to display that data on the screen. The problem is that I don't know how to create a new Todo object to pass it as parameter for addTodo function.. Thaaank you all and hope you can help me!!

I will let the code here (please see the -loadFromFile- function, there is the problematic place:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import TodoForm from './TodoForm';
import Todo from './Todo';
import data from  './data/data.json'


function TodoList() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  
  const loadFromFile = data.map( ( data) => {
    const newTodo = addTodo(new Todo(data.id,data.text));
    return  ( {newTodo} )});


  const addTodo = todo => {
    if (!todo.text || /^\s*$/.test(todo.text)) {
      return;
    }

    const newTodos = [todo, ...todos];

    setTodos(newTodos);
    console.log(...todos);
  };

  const updateTodo = (todoId, newValue) => {
    if (!newValue.text || /^\s*$/.test(newValue.text)) {
      return;
    }

    setTodos(prev => prev.map(item => (item.id === todoId ? newValue : item)));
  };

  const removeTodo = id => {
    const removedArr = [...todos].filter(todo => todo.id !== id);

    setTodos(removedArr);
  };

  const completeTodo = id => {
    let updatedTodos = todos.map(todo => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        todo.isComplete = !todo.isComplete;
      }
      return todo;
    });
    setTodos(updatedTodos);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TodoForm onSubmit={addTodo} />
      {loadFromFile}
      <Todo 
        todos={todos}
        completeTodo={completeTodo}
        removeTodo={removeTodo}
        updateTodo={updateTodo}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default TodoList;
```

I want to create new instance of Todo object. I tried many times, many different forms, but still doesn't work. I have an id and a text from the data.json file. I want to create that instance of Todo object with these two values. But how?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import TodoForm from './TodoForm';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';


const Todo = ({ todos, completeTodo, removeTodo, updateTodo }) => {
  
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState({
    id: null,
    value: ''
  });

  const submitUpdate = value => {
    updateTodo(edit.id, value);
    setEdit({
      id: null,
      value: ''
    });
  };

  if (edit.id) {
    return <TodoForm edit={edit} onSubmit={submitUpdate} />;
  }

  return todos.map((todo, index) => (
    <div
      className={todo.isComplete ? 'todo-row complete' : 'todo-row'}
      key={index}
    >
      <p> <div key={todo.id} onClick={() => completeTodo(todo.id)}>
        {todo.text}
      </div> 
      </p>

      <div className='icons'>
        <DeleteIcon fontSize="small"
          onClick={() => removeTodo(todo.id)}
          className='delete-icon'
        />
        <EditIcon
          onClick={() => setEdit({ id: todo.id, value: todo.text })}
          className='edit-icon'
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  ));
};

export default Todo;
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Fab, IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';

function TodoForm(props) {
  const [input, setInput] = useState(props.edit ? props.edit.value : '');

  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  });

  const handleChange = e => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    props.onSubmit({
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
      text: input
    });
    setInput('');
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='todo-form'>
      {props.edit ? (
        <>
          <textarea cols="10"
            placeholder='Update item'
            value={input}
            onChange={handleChange}
            name='text'
            ref={inputRef}
            className='todo-input edit'
          />
          <button onClick={handleSubmit} className='todo-button edit'>
            Save
          </button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <input
            placeholder='Add item'
            value={input}
            onChange={handleChange}
            name='text'
            className='todo-input'
            ref={inputRef}
          />
          
          <Fab color="primary" aria-label="add"> 
            < AddIcon onClick={handleSubmit} fontSize="small" /> 
          </Fab>
        </>
      )}
    </form>
  );
}

export default TodoForm;
```

Comment: The question lacks clear problem statement. It's unknown what the problem is.The  code is bulky and cannot be debugged.   See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It seems your `todo` objects are objects with at least `id`, `text`, `value`, and `isComplete` properties. What else do you need? What is `TodoForm` doing to call `addTodo` and pass it a todo object?

Comment: I want to create new instance of Todo object. I tried many times, many different forms, but still doesn't work. I have an id and a text from the data.json file. I want to create that instance of Todo object with these two values. But how?

Comment: Creating object literals is trivial, i.e. `{ id: 123, text: 'the todo text' }`. Please update your question to include all relevant code, i.e. please include the code where you are trying to create and add a todo object.

Comment: just updated my question with the last part of the code. This is all I have, please show me how can I display the values from the data.json file to look like a todo (just like the added todos through the add button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Ah, I see what you are getting at now, you are wanting to load some list of todos from an external file. The main issue I see in your code is that you are attempting to call/construct a `Todo` React component manually and this simply isn't how React works. You render data/state/props into JSX and pass this to React and React handles instantiating the components and computing the rendered DOM.

> ```
> const loadFromFile = data.map((data) => {
>   const newTodo = addTodo(new Todo(data.id, data.text));
>   return ({newTodo});
> });
> ```

`Todo` shouldn't be invoked directly, React handles this.

## Solution

Since it appears the `data` is already an array of objects with the `id` and `text` properties, it conveniently matches what you store in state. You can simply pass `data` as the initial `todos` state value.

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState(data);
```

If the data wasn't readily consumable you could create an initialization function to take the `data` and transform/map it to the object shape your code needs.

```
const initializeState = () => data.map(item => ({
  id: item.itemId,
  text: item.dataPayload,
}));

const [todos, setTodos]= useState(initializeState);
```

Running Example:

```
import data from "./data.json";

function TodoList() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(data); // <-- initial state

  const addTodo = (text) => {
    if (!text || /^\s*$/.test(text)) {
      return;
    }

    setTodos((todos) => [todo, ...todos]);
  };

  const updateTodo = (id, newTodo) => {
    if (!newTodo.text || /^\s*$/.test(newTodo.text)) {
      return;
    }

    setTodos((todos) => todos.map((todo) => (todo.id === id ? newTodo : todo)));
  };

  const removeTodo = (id) => {
    setTodos((todos) => todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id));
  };

  const completeTodo = (id) => {
    setTodos((todos) =>
      todos.map((todo) =>
        todo.id === id
          ? {
              ...todo,
              isComplete: !todo.isComplete
            }
          : todo
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TodoForm onSubmit={addTodo} />
      <Todo
        todos={todos}
        completeTodo={completeTodo}
        removeTodo={removeTodo}
        updateTodo={updateTodo}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-create-an-instance-of-an-object-in-react]

Comment: OMG YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER!! Thank you very, very much!!!!!!!

Comment: Just one more question: if I want to write to file and save any move, should I install and use "write-json-file"? Is it a good way?

Comment: @info_deniz I've not any experience with that package, but sure, sounds worth trying.

Comment: thank you again for everything!